# How use a image local on Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

Everything that I try not works, only images online works.
My code is this:

```
config: {
        items: [
            {
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        html: '<img class="logo" src="http://localhost:2606/app/view/res/img/TopLifeRank.png" /><div class="barraSeparacao"></div>'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]

    }
```

This way work's on my pc, but if I try something like this don't works:

```
 config: {
        items: [
            {
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        html: '<img class="logo" src="../res/img/TopLifeRank.png" /><div class="barraSeparacao"></div>'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]

    }
```

Someone has a idea how use local images ??

Thanks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
items: [{
            xtype: "panel",
            html: "<p><img src='resources/images/some-image.png'/></p>"
        }]
```

My folder structure for the Android-based project is this:

```
android
├───assets
│   └───www
│       ├───app
│       ├───i18n
│       ├───lib
│       ├───resources
│       │   ├───css
│       │   ├───icons
│       │   ├───images
│       │   └───startup
│       └───sdk
├───libs [...]
├───res [...]
└───src [...]
```

That's part of a [sample application for Android and iOS](https://github.com/AndiDog/thesis-code/tree/master/Sample%20application/PhoneGap%20and%20Sencha%20Touch).